# Access to python list objects by index

Tags: python

I have problem about python list index.
Assume there is a list and I access to objects in list by index.
Look at this code :

```
1: x=[["python"],]

2: x[0]
3: ['python']

4: x[0][0]
5: 'python'

6: x[0][0][0]
7: 'p'
```

It is ok until now, they are correct, but I can't understand this:

```
8: x[0][0][0][0]
9: 'p'
10:x[0][0][0][0][0][0][0][0]
11:'p'
```

Actually I don't understand why this is not an error.
 ***why line 8 and 10 are not errors ???***

Comment: What does `'p'[0]` return?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because single character (here "p") is considered as string in python and index of 0 of every string is its first character (example "p"[0]=="p").

Example

```
x[0][0][0][0] # "p" as a string (Given)
x[0][0][0][0][0] #"p" as a first character 
                 # of previous string as when 
                 # you write "p"[0]

"p"[0] # remember also prints "p" as it is 
       #  the first char
```

Answer (score 0):

That's because `x[0][0][0]` returns a String, which is `"p"`. So `x[0][0][0][0]` is `p`, because the first char of String `"p"` is `"p"`.

Try to do this:

```
s = "Hi"
s[0]
s[0][0]
```

Both s[0] and s[0][0] return "H"

Answer (score 0):

Single-char is a degenerated string sequence of length 1. Because it is a sequence, elements may be retrieved using square brackets notation. Because it is not empty (is has exactly one element) 0th element exists in it and may be retrieved.